# Why Visual Studio would fail to compile/link when creating a huge std::vector?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, stdvector, cl

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. I'm working on a home made ressources management (in replacement to Qt's qrc tool). I'm trying to embed a huge file (>4Mo) in my binary through this ressources manager. So I end up creating a huge char* array.

In examples below `...` is replaced by 4 millions of hex values separated by `,` (and splitted 10 per line, as compiler has a line length imit).

When I do:

```
static const unsigned char my_resource_data[] = { ... };
```

it compiles and links.

But when I do one of:

```
static std::vector<uint8_t> v = { ... };
static std::vector<uint8_t> v{ ... };
```

It reports an error "compiler is out of heap space"

And when I do one of:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v = { ... };
std::vector<uint8_t> v{ ... };
```

CL.exe simply crashs!

Why does using a `std::vector` make a difference in the end? Is there no way to successfully create a `std::vector` here?

Comment: When using a vector, the compiler have to create an [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) object, which is not needed for the plain array initialization. There might be a bug in creating large `std::initializer_list` objects. Perhaps you should consider other ways of initializing your vectors as a workaround?

Comment: By the way, if you're using vectors as a non-dynamic array, why not use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead? Those are aggregates like plain arrays, and so doesn't need a `std::initializer_list` for its initialization.

Comment: If it's constant static data, why do you need a (dynamic) vector for it?

Comment: 4 million hex values? That sounds like 4 MiB. That wouldn't be much for a modern computer.

Comment: @melpomene: Just because we choose this implementation to make things easier. But yes, `static unsigned char*` fits our needs.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually, why would the `std::initializer_list` have to be on heap. Couldn't it be just hardcoded in the .rodata or something similar?

Comment: @NO_NAME I haven't mentioned the heap, but where else would the ***compiler*** store some of the temporary data of the source it compiles?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it doesn't *have* to make an initializer_list, the as-if rule allows that so long as the vector ends up containing the values, anything can happen

Comment: It is evident that initialising a `std:vector` with a lot of static data is harder work for the compiler than just generating a simple string of bytes.  To be honest, I can't say I'm surprised.  I got that 'out of heap space' error doing something similar a while back (I forget now exactly what), in the process of writing a simple self-extractor.  We take a lot of compiler magic for granted these days.  Not everything is guaranteed to work and this is hardly a case that Microsoft would optimise for.